# is Shell scripts execution synchronous?

Tags: shell, sh

By default Shell scripts execution is synchronous in behaviour?

```
Script1
Script2
```

I have a script1 which will take more than 4 mins to complete and the next job is dependant on this.(Similar to producer and consumer problem).

Wanted to know whether the script2 waits till script1 complete the execution.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, could you rephrase a little? Scripts run a sequence of commands. Those commands can be 'backgrounded' if needs be, but aren't by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While i'm not fully sure what you want to know, here are some common things.

You can run paralell scripts - sending them to the background, like:

```
script1 &
script2 &
script3 &
```

all 3 script will run in "parallel".

Now probably what you want to know - serial execution, when the second is depend on first.

It is achieved with `pipe` mechanism. Imagine:

```
long_running_script_what_produdes_lines | wc -l
```

both programs are run simultaneously, and the `wc` waits for the output from the `long_running_script_what_produdes_lines` and will count the the all lines.

Here are other `IPC` (InterProcess communication) methods too, (e.g. named pipes, signals).

If you need to know something other, please rephrase the question.

Comment: What about the `&&`? When running commands in the terminal I use to put && if I want them to serial. Like having an alias for `goto='cd to/some/folder'` - then I can do `goto && cd deeper/folder`. Don't know if this is the same in `.sh` scrips?